# How can I list which TCP Congestion Control Algorighm my Android device is using?

Tags: applications, networking, downloading, uploads

How can I enumerate the complete list of [TCP Congestion Control Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control#Algorithms) that my Android device supports? And how can I see which apps are using which algorithm?

I'm trying to figure out why some open-source apps suck so bad at uploading and downloading on networks with bad [Goodput](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodput) (eg high packet loss, jitter, and latency).

One thing that can be done to [drastically improve Goodput on poor networks](https://atoonk.medium.com/tcp-bbr-exploring-tcp-congestion-control-84c9c11dc3a9) is to modify the TCP Congestion Control Algorithm. Doing so requires both the server and the client to support a given algorithm. So the first step is to determine which algorithms are available, which are [provided by the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73258421/which-tcp-congestion-control-algorighms-are-supported-and-used-by-okhttp) (Android).

How can I get a list of all the TCP Congestion Control Algorithms that my Android device supports?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73258421/which-tcp-congestion-control-algorighms-are-supported-and-used-by-okhttp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list available TCP Congestion Control Algorithm (CCA):

```
adb shell sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control
```

To list allowed TCP CCA:

```
adb shell sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_allowed_congestion_control
```

To display which TCP CCA is currently used:

```
adb shell sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control
```

Example on a stock Pixel 3a:

```
sargo:/ $ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control
net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control = cubic reno

sargo:/ $ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_allowed_congestion_control
net.ipv4.tcp_allowed_congestion_control = cubic reno

sargo:/ $ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
```

---

References:

- [Android Modders Guide - TCP Algorithms](https://androidmodguide.blogspot.com/p/tcp-algorithms.html)
- [XDA - [KERNEL][OC][STOCK/CROMI] JB 4.2.1 ★ Hundsbuah ★ 10.6.1.14.10 ★ v3.4.0 ★ BETA v3.4.4, post #1881](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/kernel-oc-stock-cromi-jb-4-2-1-hundsbuah-10-6-1-14-10-v3-4-0-beta-v3-4-4.2143093/post-48045784)
- [Android Code Search - kernel/tests/net/test/sysctls_test.py](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:kernel/tests/net/test/sysctls_test.py)